# DB2 v6r1m0 DateTime support

Tags: db2, db2-400

Does the iSeries support a DateTime analogous type.  If so, where is it specifically mentioned in published IBM docs. We will be using this from .Net, so if there are any known issues that would be good to know.

- DB2 iSeries
- V6R1M0
- `DateTime` or similar data type(s).  We are usually interested in the Date part only

I really can't believe that I am reduced to asking this, but I need an authoritative answer. The links I can find reference v5 mostly. I need solid external proof to counter one of the more *interesting* statements made by a dba that is causing havoc on app dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 for i most definitely supports those data types.  The [IBM i 6.1 Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahg/icmain.htm) has a [database section](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahg/rzahgdb.htm) with information about [Date/Time data types](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzch2datetime.htm)

- [Date](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzch2date.htm)
- [Time](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzch2time.htm)
- [Timestamp](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzch2timestamp.htm)